# Function is updating every item in my Database Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I made this function to be able to be usable multiple times using different urlsConf and now every element in my Item model is updating with the same data. I made a few changes from when it last worked properly.

Major change 1: changed my Items model from abstract table to multi-table-inheritance.

Major change 2: I refactored the function to be usable multiple times(prior to this i was rewriting the same function on multiple places.
My Function should only update one element on the Item Db. I can't find why is behaving as it is.

the function in **views.py**:

```
#=========================================================================== #
#   REUSABLE FUNTIONS TO GET CUANTITIES AND TOTALS
# =========================================================================== #

# Recibe un el nombre del link en formato x-incremento o x-decremento 
# y lo parte y guarda en una lista como incremento o decremento
# GETS THE CONTENT FROM URL LIKE THIS XX-incremento OR XX-decremento, REMOVE AND APPEND TO strlist WITHOUT xx_ ("incremento" or "decremento")

def split_s(get_link):
    l = get_link.split('-')
    strlist = []
    for i in l:
        strlist.append(i)
    return strlist[1]

# Actualiza el valor cantidad existente
# UPDATES EXISTING QUATITY DEPENDING THE URL INCREMENTS OR DECREMENTS 
def calcular_nueva_cantidad(ce, up, strlist):
    if strlist == 'incremento':
        total = ce + up
    elif strlist == 'decremento':
        total = -(ce - up)
    else:
        print(F'========> {strlist} no es valido  <=========')
    return total

# Calcula el nuevo valor de cantidad existente
# CALCULATES NEW EXISTING QUANTITY
def calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu):
    return nce * pu

# crea el formulario para la actualizacion de cantidad existente
class updateForm(forms.Form):
    update = forms.IntegerField()

# MAIN FUNCTION THAT MAKES ALL THE CHANGES PER ITEM
def actualizar_cantidad(request, pk, model, reverselink ):
    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la cantidad_existente 
    cantidad_existente = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('cantidad_existente')
    c = cantidad_existente.values_list('cantidad_existente', flat=True)
    ce = c[0]
    # print(F'=========>{ce }<=========') 

    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la precio_unitario 
    precio_unitario = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('precio_unitario')
    p = precio_unitario.values_list('precio_unitario', flat=True)
    pu = p[0]
    # print(F'=========>{pu }<=========') 

    # Obteiene item id del tipo de cortador asi puede regresar a la pantalla del listado
    pp = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('tipo')
    ppp = pp.values_list('tipo', flat=True)
    pk = ppp[0]
    # print(F'=========>{pk }<=========') 

    # trae de la base de datos el valor de la total
    qs_total = model.objects.values('total')
    # print(F'=========>{qs_total }<=========') 

    if request.method =='POST':
        form = updateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # captura valor del formulario y lo limpia
            up = form.cleaned_data['update']

            # Obtiene el name de urls para el link segun sea el caso
            get_link = split_s(resolve(request.path_info).url_name)
            #print(F'=========>{get_link }<=========') # Chek que regresa get_link

            # Calcula el nuevo valor de cantidad existente 
            nce = calcular_nueva_cantidad(up, ce, get_link)

            # Actualiza la nueva cantidad existente  
            cantidad_existente.update(cantidad_existente=nce)

            # Calcula el nuevo valor de cantidad existente 
            s_total = calcular_nuevo_total(nce, pu)
            # Actualiza la nueva cantidad existente 
            qs_total.update(total=s_total)


            return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(reverselink, args=(pk, )))
        else:
            # Redirect to fail page after POST
            return HttpResponse('')
    else:
        form = updateForm()
    return render(request, 'inventario/update.html', {'form':form})

# =========================================================================== #
#   END REUSABLE FUNTIONS TO GET CUANTITIES AND TOTALS
# =========================================================================== #
```

**my models.py:**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=30,)
    numero_parte = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    proveedor = models.ForeignKey(Proveedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cantidad_existente = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    update = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
    cantidad_minima = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    precio_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
    asignado_a = models.ForeignKey(Empleados, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    anaquel = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ANAQUEL, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_x = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    posicion_en_y = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField()

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.total = self.cantidad_existente * self.precio_unitario
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)


class Cortadores(Item):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipos_Cortadores,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filos = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GABILANES)
    diametro = models.ForeignKey(Diametros, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitud = models.ForeignKey(Longitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    desbaste = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DESBASTE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cortadores"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:cortadores-list', kwargs={'id': self.tipo.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s %s %s' % (  str(self.tipo), str(self.material), str(self.filos), str(self.diametro), 
                                        self.longitud, self.desbaste
                                        )


class Tornillos(Item):
    tipo =  models.ForeignKey(Tipo_Tornillo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    paso = models.ForeignKey(Paso_Tornillo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Materiales, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitud = models.ForeignKey(Longitud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tornillos"


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('inventario:tornillos-list', kwargs={'id': self.tipo.id})

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s %s' % (str(self.tipo), str(self.paso), str(self.material), str(self.longitud))
```

**my ulrs.py**

```
# http://<domain.com>/nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-cortadores/<id-cortador>/incrementa/
path('nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-cortadores/<int:pk>/inc/', 
    views.actualizar_cantidad, 
    # DICIONARIO PASA VARIABLE CON MODELO Y EL LINK PARA REVERSE 
    {'model':Cortadores, 'reverselink':'inventario:cortadores-list'}, 
    name='c-incremento' 
),

path('nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-cortadores/<int:pk>/dec/', 
    views.actualizar_cantidad, 
    # DICIONARIO PASA VARIABLE CON MODELO Y EL LINK PARA REVERSE 
    {'model':Cortadores, 'reverselink':'inventario:cortadores-list'}, 
    name='c-decremento'
),


# INCREMENTO O DECREMENTO DE TORNILLOS 
path('nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-tornillos/<int:pk>/inc/', 
    views.actualizar_cantidad, 
    # DICIONARIO PASA VARIABLE CON MODELO Y EL LINK PARA REVERSE 
    {'model':Tornillos, 'reverselink':'inventario:tornillos-list'}, 
    name='t-incremento' 
),
path('nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-tornillos/<int:pk>/dec/', 
    views.actualizar_cantidad, 
    # DICIONARIO PASA VARIABLE CON MODELO Y EL LINK PARA REVERSE 
    {'model':Tornillos, 'reverselink':'inventario:tornillos-list'}, 
    name='t-decremento'
),
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Hi, Sorry  my function shouldn't update all values in items just the one  item that the function is called on. I can't find the reason

Comment: Which fields are being updated in all the objects?

Comment: The total is being updated with the same quantity for every item

Comment: I already did something like that... let me try to find the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your objects are being updated with the same `total` for each item because of this line here (line 44 of `actualizar_cantidad`):

```
qs_total.update(total=s_total)
```

You defined `qs_total = model.objects.values('total')`, which means every object of class `model`, so when you call `update`, you're updating all of them.

To fix this, either redefine qs_total to only be the object or objects that you are interested in updating, using `filter`, or remove this line.

Comment: Thanks. Can i Use something like: 

` qs_total.filter(pk=pk).update(total=s_total)`  

to solve this situation?

Comment: That will work, but using `get` instead of `filter` would be better in that situation since you are only interested in getting one object, and `get` returns a single object instead of a queryset.

Comment: tried implementing both :

`qs_total.filter(pk=pk).update(total=s_total)
qs_total.get(pk=pk).update(total=s_total)`


while using the **filter()** only updates the first item in my DB  using the **get()** does not updated any items

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. `update` is a method of queryset, not an object. So you must use `filter`.

Comment: When you say `filter` only updates the first item in your DB, do you mean just the first one ordered by `id`? Or it does what you mean it to?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that

Comment: Is it updating the correct item or just the first one in your table?

Comment: is updating the first one on my table

Comment: Ok. so now I'm noticing some other issue that will relate to this one. as a bottom line I can say now it working properly -sh!  the issue I'm now having is the way I generate this view.  what I'm doing is generating a view that gets a list of tool types to act as categories, every category has an id  so when i click on the category i takes me to a list of items that belong to this cat.

Comment: Are you defining `qs_total` as it was before? Perhaps you should just do `model.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(total=s_total)`

Comment: curently no matter what item I choose to upgrade it goes to id=1

Comment: It might be how you have set up your links. What happens if you type directly in to the address bar: host + "nuevos-articulos/herramientas-de-corte/categoria-cortadores/2/inc/"? Does the Cortador with id 2 get updated?

Comment: O.K.  We got it working! thanks ... Yes I had defined like this : `qs_total = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('total')` then I flattened the value : `t = qs_total.values_list('total', flat=True)` and got the 1st item on the resulting list: `tt = t[0]`  that did the trick for  adding the right quantities the second issue i started having was it was only updating the first item was dues to this condition:

Comment: `# Obteiene item id del tipo de cortador asi puede regresar a la pantalla del listado
 pp = model.objects.filter(pk=pk).values('tipo')
 ppp = pp.values_list('tipo', flat=True)
 pk = ppp[0]
 print(F'=========>{ppp }<========= id') `  this gets the id of the element that is being updated and i was calling it  before i made the assignment to total, so i just moved  my **qs_total** line before  **pp** and everything works  fine now

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! You are awesome

Comment: Its weird... i saw this same code before... with the same author, but i could not find my anwer... this is a duplicated post or different problem at same code?

Comment: @DiegoVinícius . Same code different issue. After making the changes you recommended me about changing from Abstract class to model inheritance! i posted a new question because i did not know if i could add an other issue on the same post Thanks

Comment: nope, you did it right, if is different issue is different post :)

Answer (score 0):

About your question `qs_total.update(total=s_total)` will update every object that have this same total amount, to be specific and update only one you must pass some **unique value as id**

On this line of code `qs_total = model.objects.values('total')` dont use keyword "model", This comes to you as text, so the name of your class in string dont means that is the instance of the class, you need get it first and than runs the queryset

**Suggestion:**
I did something like that before, i hope it helps you, or maybe you can improve something at your main code

```
'''
    In this version accepts only integer or decimal fields
    Parameters:
    1 - Queryset
    2 - Column Name(String)
    3 - Filter(String):
            - Less Than Equal - "-<valor>" | Example: "-250"
            - Between - "<valor>~<valor>" | Example: "250~350"
            - Greater Than Equal - "+<valor>" | Example: "+15"            
    '''

    def dinamic_filter(queryset, column, filter):
        if '-' in filter:
                filter = filter.replace('-','')
                queryset = queryset.filter(**{'{column}__lte'.format(column=column):int(filter)})
        elif '~' in filter:
            values = filter.split('~')
            if values[0] and values[1]:
                less = valores[0]
                greater = valores[1]
                queryset = queryset.filter(**{'{column}__range'.format(column=column):(less, greater)})
            else:
                raise ValidationError('Wrong Value {filter} of column {column}'.format(filter=filter, column=column))
        elif '+' in filtro:
            filter = filter.replace('+','')
            queryset = queryset.filter(**{'{column}__gte'.format(column=column):int(filter)})

        return queryset
```

Source: https://github.com/Diegow3b/django-dinamic-queryset-filter

Comment: Thanks @Diego Vinicius